# Null Pointer Exception when try to configure widjget from configuration activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I have one widget in that it will be configured by one activity, in that i can change look of widget from activity... acitivity will open only first time when user trying to add widget at that time only activity will be called first now user change it's setting and when press save button widget will be updated.

```
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.getMinSpanForWidget(Launcher.java:1234)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.completeAddAppWidget(Launcher.java:1270)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.access$1000(Launcher.java:121)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher$4.run(Launcher.java:766)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.launcher2.Workspace$9.run(Workspace.java:3474)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.launcher2.DragLayer$3.onAnimationEnd(DragLayer.java:670)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1018)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:51)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:623)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:639)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:535)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-27 12:50:59.546: E/AndroidRuntime(15346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 12:50:59.548: V/Provider/Setting(353): from settings cache , name = dropbox:system_app_crash value = null
```

Here is my code, below code will be executed when i click on save button

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    Configuration.class);

            intent.putExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    0);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                            0,
                            intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Getting an instance of
            // WidgetManager
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(getBaseContext());

            // Instantiating the class RemoteViews
            // with widget_layout
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(
                    getBaseContext().getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.main);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(0, views);

            // Return RESULT_OK from this activity
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    0);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give us some context of your intention and problem, it'll make helping you that much easier.

Comment: hi @RogiervanhetSchip i am just updating widget from actvitity, in activity when i press ok it will destroy and update the widget like that

Comment: On what line does the exception occur? I don't see any of your methods in the stack trace.

Comment: ya @RogiervanhetSchip that's what i am facing, this error is shown up in logcat when i got this error dialog of crashing

Comment: Why do you think this code is the culprit?

Comment: no but when i press save button at that time only i am getting this error so that's why i believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm @Komal i got your issue there is a problem with widget_id

here in code you are passing widget id zero like

```
        resultValue.putExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                0);
```

here is the main issue instead of "0" you have to first get appwidget_id of current widget by

first declare global variable

```
     private int mAppWidgetId = 0;
```

now on onCreate() method get app widget id by

```
 mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

now put this mAppWidgetId in

```
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
```

instead of

```
 resultValue.putExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                0);
```

you will resolve issue. :)

Comment: Thanks you so much @Siddhpura Amit i resolve this issue by changing this :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) the first argument should be an appWidgetId. Are you sure this should be 0?

Also, the results of this line are not used:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```